# How to get and read an object literal from js file into Angular ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-ff3x2h). Here's my code:

**language.js**

```
var es = {
  firstDayOfWeek: 1,
  dayNames: [
    "domingo",
    ...
  ],
  dayNamesShort: ["dom", ...],
  dayNamesMin: ["D", "...]
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import * as languageVariable from "./languages.js";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(languageVariable.es);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> undefined

Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

language.js is currently not exporting your `es` object, so your import in app.component.ts is unable to import anything.

Depending on your module system, you should be able to declare `es` as an exportable member of language.js and resolve your issue.

```
// language.js
export const es = {
  firstDayOfWeek: 1,
  dayNames: [
    "domingo",
    ...
  ],
  dayNamesShort: ["dom", ...],
  dayNamesMin: ["D", ...]
};
```

[Stackblits of working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-ywyqqe?file=app/languages.js)

Comment: I think I needed this simple solution only. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: One last question. Lets say tomorrow I have 10 more object literals like this. Do I have to export all of them one by one like this or is there any way to expoert them all at once.

Comment: If you wanted to import each as it's own object, yes you would need to export them all individually. However, a valid solution like the one provided by @Shivansh Seth would also work if you wanted to import a `language` object that you could then reference specific language objects from.

Comment: Kevin and Shivansh, thanks both. I'll ask my tech lead which approach is better for our project. But to me, Shivansh's solution looks more efficient in handling multiple languages.

Answer (score 2):

For Multiple Langauge objects you can use like this with single export rest code will same as @kevin shared.

```
export const es= {
  en:{
    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
    dayNames: [
      "domingo",
      "lunes",
      "martes",
      "miércoles",
      "jueves",
      "viernes",
      "sábado"
    ],
    dayNamesShort: ["dom", "lun", "mar", "mié", "jue", "vie", "sáb"],
    dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"]
  },
  gb:{
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: [
          "domingo",
          "lunes",
          "martes",
          "miércoles",
          "jueves",
          "viernes",
          "sábado"
        ],
      dayNamesShort: ["dom", "lun", "mar", "mié", "jue", "vie", "sáb"],
      dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"]
  },
  fr:{
    
  }
  
};
```